What to do with a torn vapor barrier in shower?
We are working to renovate our bathroom tub and when taking down the tile we cut into the vapor barrier. The plan is to add in a direct-to-stud tub surround but now we are concerned about how to proceed. Is there a way to repair the vapor barrier without tearing off more drywall? Since there are dark spots on the insulation do we need to replace it? Currently we are only down to the studs where the surround would cover. 

I live in the midwest so we do get very cold winters and hot summers. Would that still be a viable option?

Refit vapor barrier. It should run in its original location behind the shower. Air can circulate behind the shower, since it's hollow, and you want to maintain the barrier.
Place a new sheet and do your best to lap behind the remaining sheets around it, and add sealing tape where you can.
I would not replace the fiberglass. If that is mold, mold is everywhere anyway. Spray it with a bleach solution if you want, but I'd just ignore it.
